# How to show the list of columns and rows containing 1 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe looks like this:

```
    F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
F1  1   1   1   1   1
F2  0   1   1   0   1
F3  0   1   1   1   1
F4  0   0   0   1   0
F5  0   1   1   1   1
```

Output I need:

```
            HOR                     VER               IS    
F1  [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]          [F1]               [F1]   
F2  [F2, F3, F5]            [F1, F2, F3, F5]     [F2, F3, F5]
F3  [F2, F3, F4, F5]        [F1, F2, F3, F5]     [F2, F3, F5]
F4  [F4]                    [F1, F3, F4, F5]         [F4]
F5  [F2, F3, F4, F5]        [F1, F2, F3, F5]      [F2,F3,F5]
```

In HOR: I want to show the list of column names containing 1 horizontally.
In VER: I want to show the list of row names containing 1 vertically.
IS is the intersection of HOR and VER

I don't know how to code this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage boolean indexing and sets. Code below

```
s=df==1#Boolean values where 1

df = df.assign(HOR = s.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1),
                  VER = s.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=0)
                  )

df['IS'] =list(df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['HOR']).intersection(set(x['VER']))), axis=1))


F1  F2  F3  F4  F5                   HOR               VER            IS
F1   1   1   1   1   1  [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]              [F1]          [F1]
F2   0   1   1   0   1          [F2, F3, F5]  [F1, F2, F3, F5]  [F5, F3, F2]
F3   0   1   1   1   1      [F2, F3, F4, F5]  [F1, F2, F3, F5]  [F5, F3, F2]
F4   0   0   0   1   0                  [F4]  [F1, F3, F4, F5]          [F4]
F5   0   1   1   1   1      [F2, F3, F4, F5]  [F1, F2, F3, F5]  [F5, F3, F2]
```